# How to prove the following condition on elements of a positive semi definite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

**Given**:
$2$x$2$ positive semi definite matrix $T$ over complex field with real elements. 
That is for every vector $v \in \mathbb{C}^2$, $v^T Tv \ge 0$ 
and   $T_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}, 1 \le i,j \le 2$ .

**To prove**: 
 
If $T_{ij}=a_{ij}$   prove that $a_{11}a_{22} \ge a_{12}a_{21}$ .

 I could not think of a way so I would really appreciate  hints only.

Comment: Hint: if you let $v=(v_1,v_2)$ and multiply out your given inequality, you'll get $v_1^2a_{11}+v_2^2a_{22}\geq-v_1v_2(a_{12}+a_{21})$, from which it's not too hard to pick (real, unitary) values for $v_1,v_2$ which give the desired result.

Comment: Do you mean $\bar{v}^TTv\geq0$ ?  (Otherwise it's not possible to be positive semidefinite unless $T=0$.)

Comment: @JamesM yes. sorry for the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *T* is positive semidefinite, then

$\det T = a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21} \ge 0$

since the determinant is just the product of the two eigenvalues of **T**, and
these are non-negative.